# Error NLTK was unable to find the java file

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Tengo un código escrito en Python que utiliza un tokenizer particular. En concreto es necesario leer un archivo de java, que tengo instalado en el directorio correspondiente.

```
german_postagger = StanfordPOSTagger(r'/Users/test/stanford-postagger/models/german-hgc.tagger', r'/Users/test/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar')
german_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("german")
```

Al correr el programa obtengo el siguiente error:

```
LookupError: 
===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

He intentado mil cosas, pero no consigo dar con la clave. ¿A alguien le es familiar este error?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece que no encuentra `java.exe`. ¿Tienes instalado el jdk?¿Tienes bien configurado el PATH (JAVAHOME) para acceder a él? ¿Que sistema operativo estas usando?

Comment: Parece que tenía instalado jre y no jdk. Ahora parece que "medio" funciona. Gracias por el comentario